# Boost 1.41 LNK1104 error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, boost, build-process

I have been using Boost 1.36 for a while without any problems. Had to upgrade to 1.41 to get PropertyTree.  Boost appears to build properly but when i try and compile the project that was using boost 1.36 I get this error.

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\dev\3rdparty\boost-build_1_41_0\boost\bin.v2\libs\filesystem\build\msvc-9.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi.obj'
```

The object file name seems invalid. threading-multi is a directory.

I built boost using

```
bootstrap
.\bjam
```

and also tried

```
bjam --build-dir=c:\dev\3rdparty\boost-build_1_41_0
  --toolset=msvc --threading=multi --without-python --runtime-link=static --buildtype=complete stage
```

both at the Vs2008 command prompt.

I have updated references to the correct boost directories in the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am relatively sure that this is not a problem with Boost itself. If it were a problem with autolink, you will not see that long path in the linker error message.

Can you create a brand new project and see if the problem reproduces? If no, check your project to see if you refer to "bin.v2" *anywhere*. Remove such references. You should only
add the 'stage/lib' directory to additional library paths.

Answer (score 0):

I think the VS version is important. Try adding -9.0. Here's my command line which works for 2008:

```
bjam --build-dir=./build --toolset=msvc-9.0 --with-system --with-filesystem --with-date_time --runtime-link-static --threading-multi --link-static --build-type=complete stage
```